# How to Remove/ Delete Taskbar for Certain User in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I need to make it clear first that i am not asking to hide the taskbar or remove icons from it

I am wondering how to completely remove the functionality of the Windows 10 Taskbar for a User account. Is there something that can be altered in the registry for this? I am trying to find a method that does not require a program I need to download. Thank you.

Comment: First, we don't use CAPS here - please edit the top part of the message, second

Comment: Apologies for that, I'll keep it in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another "option" (I don't even know whether or not to list this, but I guess there's no harm in it) is to prevent Explorer.exe from running altogether.
That's the program in charge of the taskbar, among other things.

If you happen to not need Explorer's other functionality (opening directories and exploring the file system), then this is a good idea. If you do need it then you could also consider an alternative file explorer (I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), myself).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think this method of removing the taskbar will be best for my case.

Answer (score 0):

And second, the only way how to accomplish this is to use what Microsoft calls a kiosk mode. However this is not a simple setting that can be switched - you need to send XML payload to the OS, that meets the MDM standard or via the Configuration Designer - learn more on [Microsoft web](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions)